# what is the difference between Android Native browser and Chrome

Tags: android, browser, native

Does anybody know if there is any difference between recently launched google chrome and the native browser of android (in Development perspective)?

Comment: I would also rephrase question, what could be considered default one? Latest Androids (at least vendor versions of it) come with both on board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the following links which should give my answer but not satisfied though,

- https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/faq
- http://news.softpedia.com/news/Chrome-for-Android-Comes-with-Advanced-Developer-Tools-251500.shtml
- http://androidandme.com/2012/02/applications/goodbye-old-browser-chrome-to-become-the-standard-browser-on-android-4-0-and-above/
- https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/overview

If anyone has more proper answer, please let me know.